# Beautifulsoup selecting the element that contains certain attribute

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I would like to select the second element by specifying the fact that it contains "title" element in it (I don't want to just select the second element in the list)

```
sample = """<h5 class="card__coins">
 <a class="link-detail" href="/en/coin/smartcash">SmartCash (SMART)</a>
 </h5>
 <a class="link-detail" href="/en/event/smartrewards-812" title="SmartRewards">"""
```

How could I do it?
My code (does not work):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(sample.content, "html.parser")
second  = soup.find("a",  {"title"})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for I in soup.find_all('a', title=True):
    print(I)
```

After looping through all `a` tags we are checking if it contains title attribute and it will only print it if it contains title attribute.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do this is by using [CSS selector](https://beautiful-soup-4.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html?highlight=select_one#css-selectors)

```
soup.select_one('a[title]')
```

this selects the first `a` element having the `title` attribute.